# Building complex rest API express.js requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest

I have a database which has the following structure. I need to write a request that will issue a post, by user_id and id.

```
 id |           title            |           content           | user_id 
----+----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------
```

This is the route I tried but it doesn't work.

```
router.put('/post/:user_id&id', updatePost);
```

This is a controller, I do not understand how to correctly pass data for a correct request to the Database

```
async updatePost(req, res) {
    try {
        const id = req.query.id
        const user_id = req.query.user_id
        const {title, content} = req.body
        const updatePost = await db.query(`UPDATE post SET title = $1, content = $2 WHERE id = $3 AND user_id = $4`, [title, content, id, user_id])
        res.json(updatePost.rows)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error when update a post:', err)
        res.status(500).json({error: 'Something went wrong, try again later. Res status - 500'})
    }
    
}
```

I also try next route

```
router.put('/post/:user_id/:id', updatePost); 
// But I don't understand how the controller takes the data for user_id and id
```

Comment: Add validation for your request. Check Joi (https://joi.dev)

Comment: if you have not yet, review the express documentation for routes and parameters https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up two different concepts.

[Route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) are defined with `router.put('/post/:user_id/:id'`, sent in the URL with `http://example.com/post/myUserId/myid/` and appear in [`req.params`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params).

A [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is **not** defined in the route (`router.put('/post/',`, sent in the URL with `http://example.com/post/?user_id=myUserId&id=myid` and appear in [`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

Answer (score 1):

Basically what Quentin has answered. Express on node is quite helpful and easy system to build on top of.

You should decide how you would like to structure this route, query parameters or route parameters.

this is an answer for route parameters

```js
router.put('/post/:user_id/:id', updatePost);

async updatePost(req, res) {
  try {
    const id = req.id
    const user_id = req.user_id
    const {
      title,
      content
    } = req.body
    const updatePost = await db.query(`UPDATE post SET title = $1, content = $2 WHERE id = $3 AND user_id = $4`, [title, content, id, user_id])
    res.json(updatePost.rows)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error when update a post:', err)
    res.status(500).json({
      error: 'Something went wrong, try again later. Res status - 500'
    })
  }

}
```